# Can I meld a creature if I've mutated it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-meld

What happens if I activate the melding ability of a creature while I both own and control it and the other half, but —

- Scenario 1: I have mutated under the creature?
- Scenario 2: I have mutated over the creature, then turned the merged permanent into a copy of the original creature?

The comprehensive rules for meld don't mention mutate. The rules for merging permanents say only this about meld:

> **726.2j** A face-up merged permanent that contains a double-faced card or meld card can’t be turned face down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can meld using a merged permanent. The other components of the merged permanent stay in exile.**

Meld effects, like on [Gisela, the Broken Blade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gisela%2C%20the%20Broken%20Blade) are written like this:

> At the beginning of your end step, if you both own and control Gisela, the Broken Blade and a creature named Bruna, the Fading Light, exile them, then meld them into Brisela, Voice of Nightmares.

First, the effect checks if you own and control a creature with the specified name, but that is all that it requires, so the creature can be a copy, or merged, or have its name changed, and the effect will still happen. The first thing the effect does is exile the two permanents. The specific result of this is described in [rule 721.3 and subrules](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr721/):

> **721.3.** If a merged permanent leaves the battlefield, one permanent leaves the battlefield and each of the individual components are put into the appropriate zone.
>
> - **721.3c** If an effect can find the new object that a merged permanent becomes as it leaves the battlefield, it finds all of those objects. (See rule 400.7.) If that effect causes actions to be taken upon those objects, the same actions are taken upon each of them.

Then the effect instructs you to meld the cards. Because of rule 721.3c, it actually instructs you to meld all of the exiled cards. The [meld rules](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr701/#36) describe how this is handled:

> **701.36a** Meld is a keyword action that appears in an ability on one card in a meld pair. (See rule 712, “Meld Cards.”) To meld the two cards in a meld pair, put them onto the battlefield with their back faces up and combined. The resulting permanent is a single object represented by two cards.
>
> **701.36b** Only two cards belonging to the same meld pair can be melded. Tokens, cards that aren’t meld cards, or meld cards that don’t form a meld pair can’t be melded.
>
> **701.36c** If an effect instructs a player to meld cards that can’t be melded, they stay in their current zone.

So, you can only actually meld the cards belonging to the meld card. In this example, that would be Gisela, the Broken Blade, and Bruna, the Fading Light. The other components of the merged permanent cannot be melded, so they stay in exile.

Comment: I don't know if I would interpret 701.36c the same way as you do. If it said "If an effect instructs a player to meld **a card** that can't be melded, **it** stays" then I would agree with you. The meldable component of the merged permanent can certainly be melded, but the combination of both cards cannot be melded with the other half. After all, 721.3c says that the action is taken on all the objects, which I would understand as meaning that both cards of the merged permanent attempt to meld as one half.

Comment: Once the components of the merged permanent are exiled, they are separate cards, no longer part of a single object. 721.3c says to take the action on "each" of the permanents, which indicates that you should consider them separately. And I think the wording difference for 701.36c doesn't matter here. Another way of looking at it is that when you apply 721.3c to the meld action, you are trying to meld each pair of the single card and each component of the merged permanent. For each pair where one component is not a meldable permanent, the cards stay in exile. For the correct pair, they meld.

Comment: @CainGoldhardt it specifies "a card" not "an object" while the melded stack is a single game object (until it is exiled) it is still made up of several individual cards, only one of which is actually reference by the meld. The rule you are quoting there is more meant to handle melding with [clone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370622)s or token copies of a card that would have been able to meld if it were the original card.